# Word or phrase for customers won from a competitor

Tags: expressions

In the context of a company that makes or sells a product (e.g. accounting software) where there are many alternatives on the market, is there a word or [short] phrase to describe "*new customers that have been persuaded to switch from a competitor's product*" as opposed to "*new customers who have never used such a product before*"?

Both categories are "*new business*" (to the company concerned), but the first scenario is about redistributing market share as opposed to growing the total market.

For example, "*the following changes are proposed to the software to attract* ___________ [transferring customers] *from users of RivalCo's offering.*"

Following [Josh61's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337364/102510), I realise the example above wasn't perfect, as I wanted a term more for customers who had been won than prospective ones... a better example would be "*The changes in Version 3 enabled us to win a number of* __________ *users from RivalCo's offering*."

Comment: *Defectors*? Or maybe you just want to *poach* some clients?

Comment: I misunderstood your question when I posted my initial answer. I don't think there is such a word or phrase in English. You need to rephrase the sentence to use "verb + noun".

Comment: If you remove from out of your first sentence example then the word "current" fits into both contexts as both sentences already define "users"

Comment: Clientele converted from RivalCo were as a result of changes implemented in Version 3. Or. Version 3 enabled the conversion of RivalCo's existing clientele to our custom.

Comment: *Converts* works where there is some reasonable brand identity and you are referring to retail customers.

Comment: Cannibalized means A aggressively conquered portions of B by a ruthless show of strength. Typically, it is used to mean that A will harm its own product X by producing a simpler version X' to sell for less. When customers move to X', A has cannibalized its own line. So you take customers by cannibalizing a competitor's line. Not cannibalizing the customers, but the market share.